# How do I reassociate "Enable Smart Invert" with Siri voice command?

Tags: iphone, display, siri, accessibility

I recently updated my iPhone 12 to the latest iOS (v 16.4.1).  Previously, I could tell Siri, "Enable Smart Invert" or "Disable Smart Invert" and the setting in Accessiblity -> Display and Text Size would change accordingly.

[image]

Now when I try this, Siri says "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that."  Is there a way to re-enable this voice command?

Comment: I’ve tried to reproduce this on an iPhone 12 mini and a 13 (not sure which variant, but not mini) both  running iOS 13.3.1 and I can’t get it to fail.  Even if I manually disable it, I can use Siri to enable by saying “Enable Smart Invert.”  Is there something specific about your use case?  Do you have a particular accent or vocal intonation that may be difficult for Siri to recognize?

Comment: When you say “the latest iOS” what do you mean by that?  What version *specifically*?

Comment: Try saying “Invert Colors” to enable and “Turn off Invert Colors.”  I was testing this on my iPad (iPadOS 16.4.1) and found a small discrepancy  in how this worked.  This phraseology works on iPad, my previous comment works on iPhone.

Comment: @Allan, updated the question -- 16.4.1.  When I tried your commands they do indeed work.  Thanks!

Comment: I’ll post as an answer.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing on an iPhone 12 mini and an iPhone 13 (not mini) both running iOS 13.3.1 as well as an iPad running iOS 16.4.1.

To invert the colors, just say any of the following:

- *Invert Colors* (Enables Smart Color Invert)
- *Turn On/Off Invert Colors*
- *Enable/Disable Invert Colors*

If you want the Classic Invert Colors, say the following:

- Enable/Disable Classic Invert Colors
- Turn On/Off Classic Invert Colors

There is a discrepancy between iOS and iPadOS where the phrase “*…Smart Invert Colors*” is not recognized on iOS, but is on iPadOS.  If you just leave out the word “smart” for now, you should having it working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to say is **"invert screen"**
if I try "enable smart invert" it doesn't work either.

Comment: What's the command for the opposite of that (disable smart invert)?

Comment: So the opposite (disable Smart Invert) would be something like "stop inverting screen"? And this does not work for me. What iOS version are you running?

Comment: It's the latest, whatever that is.  Just updated last week.  That's when the previous commands I was using no longer worked.

Comment: Forgot I could just ask Siri what version it is -- 16.4.1.

Comment: @Dave Thanks but my comment was addressed to the answerer (Rivers). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the name of the feature is different in Siri now, it's called **Smart Invert Colors**. This is quite surprising because in Settings > Accessibility > Display & Text Size, the parameter is named "Smart Invert".

The feature called Voice Control contains commands that are all usable with Siri.

I have went over to Settings > Accessibility > Voice Control > Customize commands > Accessibility and seen that there were commands to perform the wanted actions (turn off/on Smart Invert).

#### Turn *on* Smart Invert

Say "**Turn Smart Invert Colors on**" or "**Turn on Smart Invert Colors**".

[image]

#### Turn *off* Smart Invert

Say "**Turn Smart Invert Colors off**" or "**Turn off Smart Invert Colors**".

[image]

Note : Of course, to make it work, you need to have the command enabled.

---

#### Additional info - bonus :

There is also a command to turn on/off Classic Invert Colors.

Classic Invert Colors will just invert everything, not only specific things like Smart Invert Colors do.

To turn it on, say "*Turn on Smart Invert Colors*" or "*Turn Smart Invert Colors on*".

To turn it off, say "*Turn off Smart Invert Colors*" or "*Turn Smart Invert Colors off*".

Note : You cannot have both Smart Invert Colors and Classic Invert Colors *on* at the same time. Let's say, if SIC is enabled and you try to turn on CIC, it will disable SIC and enable CIC.

Comment: Interestingly when I look at the voice commands, I confirm that "Turn on Smart Invert Colors" is listed and enabled, but when I say it, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Dave You are right, I have just checked on my iPhone and it's not working although it is on my iPad. I've went over the same setting on iPhone and it says that you should say "Turn on Invert Colors" instead of "Turn on Smart Invert Colors".